# Is it okay to only provide clickjacking protection on the login page?

Tags: clickjacking, cross-frame-scripting

I have a question about Clickjacking.

The question is quite simple.  Imagine a login flow like this:

1. You visit the application login page, eg https://example.com/login.html. There is no Clickjacking protection (i.e. the `X-Frame-Options` header) on this page.
2. This page redirects you to the SSO page to actually login, e.g. https://sso.service.com and the actual credentials are entered here.  Clickjacking protection is enabled here.
3. After logging in you are redirected back to the site, https://example.com/home.html.  There is no clickjacking protection anywhere on the site.

My question is: if I have protection on the login/SSO page alone and don't have protection in any other page of the application, is my application still vulnerable to Clickjacking?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple and straight-forward:

**Having clickjacking protection only on the login page only protects the login page.  The rest of your site is still vulnerable**

It sounds like you have a bit of a misunderstanding, and are hoping that because the login page is clickjacking-protected, someone can't use clickjacking to attack your site.  Unfortunately that is not the case.  Clickjacking (typically) relies upon using the credentials of an already-logged in user.  As a result, there is no need to target the login page with clickjacking.  Rather, you target any other page that has a sensitive action.

In fact, the login page is probably low on the list of pages that need clickjacking protection.  The reason is because you can't use clickjacking to enter a password, nor would an attacker know the user's password to log them in even if it was possible.  It might be possible to use clickjacking on a login page to login a user if the browser stores the password and suggests it automatically, and then follow that up with a clickjacking attack on another action on the site, therefore building up an exploit from multiple clickjacking attacks.  In general though, using clickjacking against a login page is probably not an interesting target in-and-of itself.

As a result, you pretty much have things backward: if you had everything *but* your login page protected from clickjacking, you'd probably be fine.  If you **only** have your login page protected from clickjacking, then your clickjacking protection is useless.

Comment: Thanks Connor for the explanation. Now I have one more doubt.. Basically Clickjacking targets for sensitive information on post login. In real time scenario when you perform Clickjacking it will send as a forged request, but I have a protection for csrf. How Clickjacking gets exploited?